# block web parts in sharepoint from certain users

Tags: javascript, asp.net, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

I'm looking to see if it's possible to block certain data in web parts from loading or showing for certain users?

I have a SharePoint page that was written in asp.net and JavaScript. What i have is a page that runs several queries and displays them as separate web parts. I would like to be able to block certain web parts that show financial information to only show for the managers group.

I am able to just hide the web part from showing at all but that isn't necessarily helpful.

any help at all would be greatly appreciated.

thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would create a hidden div that contains the users access level (or I guess you could use an array to hold / define unique users who should or shouldnt be able to to 'see' the parts)... then just write a function that reads the hidden field and based on the user who is viewing the page, show or hide the content based on the id of the web content element / part.

I would probably try to do this on the server side though before the content in question is sent to the dom.

good luck

Comment: yeesh, sounds like this may be a lot harder than i was thinking.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be is to hide the webparts using audiences. Edit the page, edit the webpart, navigate to the properties, in the Advanced section you'll find something called "Target Audiences". Either use an existing audience (which you can create in the user profile service application) or enter a SharePoint group name (like the site members, of something alike 'managers'). Members of that group/audience will see the webpart then. Other users will not see the webpart.

Notice that this is not a security measurement. E.g. it's just preventing the rendering of the webpart, it's not preventing users from accessing the data if they know where it comes from.

Read more here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/target-content-to-specific-audiences-HA010169053.aspx

Comment: This seems to be the most viable option. since my web parts are made using a db connection and a sql string, is this still possible? I don't see anywhere under the advanced section of the web part properties to do this. Am i missing something?